# innerText/innerHTML empty even thou nativeElement prints

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, angular-test

I am accessing Markup from a child component using fixture.

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent, MyChildComponent],
  imports: [
    MatChipsModule,
  ],
}).compileComponents();
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);

const chips = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('mat-chip'));
expect(chips.length).toBe(2); // works fine
```

If i print that markup, it shows content, but if i try to access innerText/innerHtml, boith are undefined.

```
console.log(chips[0].nativeElement);
```

prints

```
<mat-chip aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true" class="mat-chip mat-focus-indicator mat-primary mat-standard-chip mat-chip-selected" color="primary" ng-reflect-color="primary" ng-reflect-selected="" role="option" selected="" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="mat-chip-ripple" />
  1
</mat-chip>
```

but

```
console.log(chips[0].nativeElement.innerText);
console.log(chips[0].nativeElement.innerHtml);
```

both print `undefined` while it should print the `<div>` and/or the `1`

Comment: try `chips[0].nativeElement.textContent`, it should print the value `1`

Comment: @Andres2142 Thanks, that worked - Life Saver!
Can you write this as an answer and maybe add a documentation Link?
I'll accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `textContent` for looking at the content of the tag as plain text. It’s most effective when you want to see what’s in an element, plus styling.

```js
const element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#myDiv'));
const value = element.nativeElement.textContent;

expect(value).toBe('some value');
```

I think the reason for using `textContent` when testing is because of the `debugElement`, since the DOM could be seen as an API for manipulating the HTML, we only have access to textContent.

In any case, when it comes to testing with Angular, I recommend this [site](https://testing-angular.com/testing-components/#testing-components), it helped me to have a better understanding of how testing works and how to use it with Angular.

Comment: Note that [textContent actually ignores styling, compared to innerText which takes it into account](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext).